# Remove header text option from the backend

Tags: wp-admin

I want to remove the *header text* option from WordPress backend, under the *Appearance->Header page* at the bottom.

[image: Screen Dump]

Is there any hook or filter to remove this option from the backend?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is controlled by theme as part of [custom header feature declaration](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_theme_support#Custom_Header).

Something like this should disable that part of the feature (you might need to adjust, depending on specific theme used):

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', function () {
    add_theme_support( 'custom-header', array( 'header-text' => false ) );
} );
```

Comment: I am using Genesis Theme. Adding _'header-text'     => false,_ to the _add_theme_support( 'custom-header', $args );_ did the trick. `$args = array(
 'flex-width'    => true,
 'width'         => 980,
 'flex-height'    => true,
 'height'        => 61,
 'header-text'     => false,
 'default-image' => get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/header.jpg',
);
add_theme_support( 'custom-header', $args );`. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just use the below code inside the "customize_register"

```
$wp_customize->remove_control( 'header_textcolor' );
```